# Employee Scheduling Template

Tags: calendar, template, schedule

There is a template from Microsoft about [Employee Scheduling](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=21904).
This however is an STP solution which doesn't work anymore starting Sharepoint 2010.
Can someone please share if you have any templates for showing the employee schedules.

Answer (score 1):

In [Free Microsoft SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint Online templates](http://www.microsoft.com/government/en-us/campaigns/pages/sharepoint-templates.aspx) try "Employee Training Scheduling and Materials" template!

Comment: It requires me to create a separate site while all I am trying to accomplish is to use a Calendar.